# My question is, why "pride"?

Tags: british-english

A Croat author wrote:

> Arrogance only breeds quarrels, but wisdom is found in those who take advice.

A British English native translated it into English like this:

> Pride only breeds quarrels, but wisdom is found in those who take advice.

My question is, why *pride*?

Comment: Maybe this person believes pride is more likely to cause quarrels than arrogance, or that that's a better translation. Or maybe he thinks pride and arrogance are synonymous (which they sometimes but not always are). We really can't tell you what's going on in his head.

Comment: You should provide the original sentence, words can have more than one meaning and interpretation. You claim that the Croat author wrote "arrogance"  but how do we know for sure that he did, or that he meant to write?

Comment: In croatian language pride = ponos, arrogance = oholost and "oholost" is very very bad always, and "ponos" is always good. @m.a.a.has given excellent answer.

Comment: But pride is not always "good" in English, its negative meaning is listed first: ["**a high** or **inordinate opinion of one's own dignity, importance, merit, or superiority**, whether as cherished in the mind or as displayed in bearing, conduct, etc.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pride)

Comment: This is a Bible quote, Proverbs 13:10 _ 'Only by pride cometh contention: but with the well advised is wisdom.' (AV) // 'Pride leads to conflict; those who take advice are wise.' (// 'New Living Translation). See the [Biblehub.com/proverbs parallel translations](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/13-10.htm) for alternatives, many with clearer sentence order than the AV, and synonyms. My question is, 'Why "arrogance"?'

Comment: Pride goeth before destruction and a haughty spirit before a fall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He/She may mean it in the [7 deadly sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins) sense.

I speak no Croatian, but it seems the sin's called "[Oholost](https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedam_smrtnih_grijeha)", which equals "arrogance" according to google translate.

Comment: Arrogance is not among the seven deadly sins. Do you mean that *pride*, which is listed,  is the correct interpretation?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yup. That's exactly what I meant. A croatian word that ordinarily equals "arrogance" is also the name of one deadly sin, namely "pride", which may be the reason why this British translator opted for the latter... Thought that was clear enough.

Comment: Justification of downvote would be much appreciated, athough not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, though "pride" may be positive, it can also be used in a negative sense synonymous with "arrogance" (See entry (3) [here](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pride)). There is no exact translation for every term in other languages -- why do you think there should be one for the Croatian word you translate as "arrogance"?